# Composer ask me for update every time

Tags: composer-php

When I try to do:

```
$ sudo php composer.phar update
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
```

When I type:

```
$ sudo php composer.phar self-update
$ sudo php composer.phar update
```

the warning disappear, but the next time I want to execute the same command (not after 30 days), the warning comes again. How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there a special reason to execute the composer update command with root privileges? I'd deem that overkill and not necessary. For the self-update it might be necessary depending on where it's installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that something else overwrites your composer.phar with an old copy. If the self-update process was failing, then you would still see the warning when doing an update right after. If you don't then something must be happening in the meantime.

You can use `php composer.phar -V` to see the exact version of the phar you have. You could check after a self-update and check after a while again to see if the version changed. Maybe it's checked out in git or you have a build process reverting it or something?

Comment: Probably. I was working with two local repos and one remote. I guess one of those was rewriting others when doing push. I had a mess because I had a wrong `.gitignore` file and I wasn't able to find out the problem. Now, it's working right. Thanks.